# How can I solve this conflict between Opencv and GTKmm?

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, gtkmm

I would use the OpenCV libraries into a program using the Gtkmm graphic interface but when I try to open an image with cv::imread, there is an error message during the execution : gtk-error ** Using gtk+ 2.x and gtk+ 3 in the same process is not supported.

Here is a very simple sample code :

```
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/image.h>

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
Gtk::Image ImgGtk;
Gtk::Window Win0;
cv::Mat ImgOcv;

Win0.set_border_width(5);
Win0.set_default_size(250, 100);

ImgOcv= cv::imread("icone.png", -1);
ImgGtk.set("icone.png");
Win0.add(ImgGtk);

Win0.show_all();
Gtk::Main::run(Win0);

return 0;
}
```

The idea is to replace "ImgGtk.set("icone.png");" by a create_from_data and a gtk_img.set(pixbuf) or some things alike.
The code above compile and link fine, but produces the above mentionned error during the exceution. 
Just remove the line 17 (ImgOcv= cv::imread("icone.png", -1);) and the error disapear, the image is displayed by ImgGtk.set("icone.png");.

Does anyone have heard about this kind of conflict? Does anybody know how to debug this?

I am using gtkmm 3.0 and have upgraded opencv to 2.4.5 but this did not solve the problem.
The operating system is Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses the version 2.0 API of the GTK library, which is not compatible with the version 3.0 API which your main program is using. Specifically, GTK contains code that tries to detect when they are being combined, and then crashes to let you know you can't do that.

There are three possible courses of action:

- don't use the GUI facilities of OpenCV (preferable, but I don't know if it's possible to use only OpenCV's image-processing features without opening the GUI library)
- downgrade your program to a 2.x version of GTKmm
- upgrade OpenCV to GTK 3.0 (highly labor-intensive, although many people might thank you for doing all that work. I don't really recommend it though.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this kind and quite clear answer.  
I am using console application when programming for my own researches.  But currently I would "port" a program from a console application to a GUI application for the benefit of my colleagues.  They are used to user friendly environment and I know by experience that some (most of them really) would look as very suspicious a program that require a command three line long.

I will try the second recommendation.  
Thanks again.

Comment: With #1 you could still write your own GUI, just not use the one included in OpenCV.

Comment: **Update 2014** (This question ranks highly when the problem is Googled ;) ): When I had this problem, I found pull request [2943](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2943) (July 2014) into master took a bunch of essential methods (e.g. `imread(...)` and `imwrite(...)`) out of the GTK dependent highgui module into new independent video and image codecs modules. This means it's now much easier (previously it was very impractical) to use opencv and link against GTK3+ : just don't include the highgui module. For example, in cmake:  `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc imgcodecs)` . Best.